# Python: extract position-dependent strings from .txt and save them to different columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, readlines

I have a .txt file (output.txt) from which I want to use specific strings. The required strings start at position 13 and go to the end of a line. I would like to save them to different columns of a dataframe.

I created an empty dataframe with 4 columns:

```
cameras = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name', 'altitude', 'latitude', 'longitude'])
```

and I have tried to assign the strings to different columns

```
with open('output.txt','r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if line.startswith('name'):
                cameras['name'] = line[13:-1]
            if line.startswith('NN'):
                cameras['altitude'] = line[13:-1]
            if line.startswith('lat'):
                cameras['latitude'] = line[13:-1]
            if line.startswith('lon'):
                cameras['longitude'] = line[13:-1]
```

But apparently the dataframe is still empty. I guess it's an easier problem to fix.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should have a look at [`read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html).  Read in the file as two columns, set the index to `index // 4` and pivot. In your code, you don't append new rows, you're overwriting the same row over and over again.

Comment: you can't add new rows using `=`. It would need to create list with all values in row and use `cameras= cameras.append(row)` or `cameras = pd.concat([cameras, pd.DataFrame(row).T])`. But usually it is simpler first to create normal list with all rows and later convert this list to `DataFrame` - `df = pd.DataFrame(list_with_all_rows)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create data as an array of tuples of form `(<name>, <altitude>, <latitude>, <longitude>)`.

Then you use `pd.from_records()` to create the dataframe.

There are several pitfalls here that you should be aware of. The assumption is that the input data is rows in order 'name', 'altitude', 'latitude', 'longitude'. If the order breaks (due to missing row or incorrect order), you'll get into data incosistencies. Do strict data validations.

Please refer https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html